# EasyMock constructor with many arguments

Tags: java, constructor, arguments, partial, easymock

So Let's say I have some class defined:

```
MyClass {
   private A _a;
   private B _b;
   private C _c;

   MyClass(A a, B b, C c) {
     _a = a;
     _b = b;
     _c = c;
   }

   public someMethodIDontCareAbout() {
    _b.doSomething();
    _c.doSomething();
   }

   public someMethodIWantToTest() {
     _a.doSomething();
   }
}
```

Now, lets say that I only want to test someMethodIWantToTest(), but I don't care about the other methods. I'd rather not have to create a new MyClass object and mock classes B and C. The constructor requires them, but I have no use for them since my method I want to test only uses A.

Is there a way in easy mock to say `EasyMock.createMockBuilder(MyClass.class).withConstructor(EasyMock.createNiceMock(A.class)).createMock();`

There's no constructor that takes just class A, but that's all I want. Is there no easy way to do this without specifying B and C as well? Ideally it would create niceMocks for all the other arguments in the constructor I don't want.

Comment: You can't use `null` values?

Comment: Yeah, but if you have spring beans, there might be 30 arguments to the constructor, and It's just annoying to line up all the arguments and put 28 nulls when I only care about 2 of the arguments. I was hoping for some EasyMock fancyness.

Answer (score 1):

You need to read on how [Mockito](http://mockito.org) works.
The basic idea is that it extends you class and and overrides all methods and allows you to return what ever you want it too.

Syntax is :

```
MyClass myClass = Mockito.mock(MyClass.class);
Mockito.when(myClass.getMethod()).thenReturn(whatever);
```

Same applies to EasyMock.

```
MyClass myClass = EasyMock.createMock(MyClass.class);
EasyMock.expect(myClass.getMethod).andReturn(whatever).times(1);
```

Answer (score 1):

Actually, if you refactor the constructor to take in a Config object instead of a list of arguments, then this would be a lot easier.

i.e. If you have a Config object with getters and setters for A, B, and C, and just pass a Config object to the constructor, then you can create a niceMock for your Config object and just mock the get method for getA() and have it return whatever object you need.